# How do I allow only the owner of a an item to do something with it?

Tags: django

Could anyone explain to me how to do it? I've been trying for a while without managing to do it. I am just trying to restrict permissions so that not anyone with the right link can edit/delete a particular object

```
models.py:

class Items(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:

        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and

```
views.py

class SiteList(ListView):
    model = Items


class SiteUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Items
    form_class = SiteUpdateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('portfolio:sitelist')


class SiteDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Items
    success_url = reverse_lazy('portfolio:sitelist')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a `get_object()` (see [the inheritance hierarchy](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.1/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/)) that enforces this.

```
class MustBeAuthorGetObjectMixin:
    def get_object(self):
        obj = super().get_object()
        if obj.author != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied("...")
        return obj

# ...

class SiteUpdate(MustBeAuthorGetObjectMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
   # ....
```

This way, when `UpdateView` (well, `BaseUpdateView`) calls `self.get_object()`, it'll get your version which has the permission check.